# AngularJS Noob: How do I have multiple functions in a provider?

Tags: angularjs

I have a provider that makes a connection to my API to grab products:

```
app.provider("Product", function() {
  this.$get = ['$resource', function($resource) {
    var Product = $resource("/api/products");
    return Product;
  }];

});
```

This somehow allows me to do this in my controller:

`$scope.products = Product.query();`

How would I define an extra function that allows me to make a connection to another path`/api/product/:productId` ? I want something like `Product.get(30)` which should return something like `{name: 'Potato Chips', price: '11.22'}`

Comment: It's quite good explained in the tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed it into a factory:

```
app.factory('Product', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/products/:productId", {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
  });
}]);
```

and this allows me to do this:

```
$scope.product = Product.get({productId: id});
```